# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'groupID')

Tags: typescript, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

From googling, the error means that `groupID` is undefined. So I guess that means that `request.data.groupID` is undefined? But I did what the [docs said](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#node.js) to set this variable, so what is wrong here?

```
exports.callGroupRTDBSetup = functions.https.onCall(async (request) => {
  try {
    const groupID = request.data.groupID;
    const adminUID = request.data.adminUID;
    const adminUsername = request.data.adminUsername;
    const createdTimestamp = request.data.createdTimestamp;

    await setGroupAdminRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createdTimestamp);

    await addMemberRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createdTimestamp);

    return {
      returnVal: 1,
      returnMsg: "Success!",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "invalid-argument",
      "Error: " + error
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: The error means that you are trying to get the value of property 'groupID' from a former object that is undefined (resulting in the property not existing atm). This means that request.data is undefined in your snippet.

Comment: @TjeuFoolen right